# Could not load file or assembly 'accord.video.ffmpeg.x64.dll' or one of its dependencies

Tags: c#, ffmpeg

I'm using Accord.video.ffmpeg.x64.  My project is built in x64 as well. It is a click once windows forms application. I installed accord through nuget. C++ redistributor is installed.

Everything works fine when I run the program from debug.  But when I publish it and try to run it (on the same machine or any other machine) I get the error "could not load file or assembly 'accord.video.ffmpeg.x64.dll' or one of its dependencies."

Thank you for any help you can provide.

Comment: Maybe the library depends on another library and it can't find it. Try to open your application with the 64 bit version of [dependencywalker](http://dependencywalker.com).

Answer (score 2):

Install on the machine both

- vc_redist-2015.x64.exe
- vc_redist-2015.x86.exe

and copy all files from your Nuget packages folders

- packages\Accord.Video.FFMPEG.x64.3.8.0\lib\net(Version)
- packages\Accord.Video.FFMPEG.x64.3.8.0\build

to the installation folder of your application.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue this week, but I found the solution!  When I compared the files in the bin folder vs the application directory under programs files, the bin folder had 8 additional files that weren't in the application installed folder:

avcodec-57.dll,
avdevice-57.dll,
avfilter-6.dll,
avformat-57.dll,
avutil-55.dll,
postproc-54.dll,
swresample-2.dll,
swscale-4.dll,

These files need to be copied into the application install folder.  They can't be referenced since they aren't .net they are c++ dll.  So what I did was added the dll files directly to my project , then right click each file properties and for build action I selected "content", then for copy to output directory, I put "copy if newer."  This fixed the issue for me, so I hope it works for you too!